# How can I prevent existing categories from disappearing when I add a new category to an email item using Exchange Web Services in C#?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, categories, exchangewebservices, blueprism

I am trying to add a new category to an email item using Exchange WEB Services but when I run the code, existing categories disappear and the category I added becomes the only category.
For example an email has categories X and Y and after I add my category Z to this mail item, X and Y disappears and only category for the mail becomes Z
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Please note that I am running this code inside a software called Blue Prism a low code no code scripting software and it is near impossible to implement third party libraries etc due to corporate chain of approvals and stuff

When I do it manually on the outlook 2019 it works the way I intended
Here is the method I am using
The DLL That uses this code is Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

```
//Here I initialize exchange object and authenticate
ExchangeService exchange = null;

void ConnectEWS(string ewsURL, string _exchangeVersion, string username, string password)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate {return true;} ;
    try
    {
        exchange                = new ExchangeService();
        exchange.Url            = new Uri(ewsURL);
        exchange.Credentials    = new WebCredentials(username,password);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("failed to initialize exchange object!!="+ex.Message);
    }   
}
//here is my void method that adds a new category to an email item
void addCategoryToMail(string msgid, string category)
{
    if(exchange==null)
    {
        throw new Exception("exchange object is null!!");
    }   
    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange,msgid, BasePropertySet.IdOnly );
    if(message.Categories.Contains(category)==false)
    {
        message.Categories.Add(category);
        //message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
        message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to get the existing categories first, add the new one to the list and then set the property.

Comment: Hello Eugene
Thank you for your comment. I also tried the following method but results are identical
`EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange,msgid, BasePropertySet.IdOnly );
 if(message.Categories.Contains(category)==false)
 {
  StringList cates = message.Categories;
  cates.Add(category);
  message.Categories = cates;
  message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
 }`
I first created a StringList variable and assigned the categories then I added the new category to this StringList then I assigned this object onto the message variable then I updated the message var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange,msgid, BasePropertySet.IdOnly );
```

only requests the message id. You need to request categories. See if `BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties` brings categories in. If not, explicitly request categories.

Comment: Thank you so much Dimitry, this is the exact source of my problem. I looked at the MS documentation and it appears I can call the Bind() method with only exchange object and my messageID This works just like the way I wanted
Best wishes
`EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange,msgid);`